# How can I determine the specific character file with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a file.

```
c:\\[test^!#$%&'()=~{`}_+-^[];.,] test.xlsx
```

but powershell test-path error.

```
PS C:\\> Test-Path -LiteralPath "C:\\[test^!#$%&'()=~{`}_+-^[];.,] test.xlsx" -PathType Leaf

PS C:\\> False

PS C:\\> Test-Path "C:\\[test^!#$%&'()=~{`}_+-^[];.,] test.xlsx" -PathType Leaf

PS C:\\> False
```

Does anyone have some ideas on how to go about this?
Thanks!

Comment: $a=“C:\Program Files (x86)[test^!#$%&'()=~{`}_+-^[];.,] test.xlsx” 
$f =@' 
$a 
'@ 
test-path -literalpath $f 
False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, having such file names is begging for trouble. They are much more trouble than help.

That being said, Powershell [quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7) explains how to work with quotes. Since there is a single quote in the file name, it must be escaped by doubling it - the usual backtick doesn't help here. Here-Strings work too. Like so,

```
# single quote twice
test-path -literalpath '[test^!#$%&''()=~{`}_+-^[];.,] test.xlsx'
True

# here-string
test-path -literalpath @'
>> [test^!#$%&'()=~{`}_+-^[];.,] test.xlsx
>> '@
True

# here-string in varialbe
$f =@'
>> [test^!#$%&'()=~{`}_+-^[];.,] test.xlsx
>> '@

test-path -literalpath $f
True
```

Comment: thank you for your help.
if (test-path @' $path '@) is ok ?

Comment: No problem. If this answers the question, click the [accept checkmark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). By doing this, others who read the question later know if the answer actually works.

Comment: sorry 
$a=“C:\Program Files (x86)\[test^!#$%&'()=~{`}_+-^[];.,] test.xlsx”
$f =@'
$a
'@
test-path -literalpath $f
False